# Two complex functions whose real parts are equal vary only by a constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be a bounded domain with boundary $B$. Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are both analytic on $D$ and continuous on $D \cup B$, and suppose further that $Re (f(z))=Re(g(z))$ for all $z\in B$. Show that $f=g+i\alpha$ in $D$, where $\alpha$ is a real constant.

Comment: Try the special case where $g\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to follow from the Cauchy Riemann equations

Let $f  = u + iv$ and $g = a + ib$.  Then $u = a$, and $u_x = v_y = b_y$, so $(v - b)_y = 0$ and similarly $u_y = -v_x = -b_x$, so $v_x - b_x = (v - b)_x = 0$.  Therefore, $v - b$ has to be constant.